# Setting data source to an raw ID in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In MediaPlayer.create method an id to a Raw file can be used but how to use that in setDataSource method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can load the raw audio into an input stream and load it into a MediaPlayer as you would a normal stream:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example);
```

and then follow a streaming tutorial like [pocketjourney](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)

But this is overly complicated as you can just call

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(counterstrikesb.this, R.raw.example);
```

Comment: Relevant part of the documentation: "Note that since `prepare()` is called automatically in this method, you cannot change the audio stream type, audio session ID or audio attributes of the new MediaPlayer."

Comment: Link to pocketjourney in answer is dead.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the actual question of the OP: you can not set an input stream in setDataSource...

Answer (score 63):

Refer to the source [android.media.MediaPlayer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.create%28android.content.Context,int%29)

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
if (afd == null) return;
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
```

You may want to add try-catch to the block.

Comment: Thanks very much! I incorporated this into the following answer which contains a full function for playing an alarm sound from a resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390067/826946

Comment: why are you calling `afd.close()` immediately after?  doesn't that invalidate the descriptor so it can't be used???

Answer (score 21):

paraphrasing @Kartik's answer here [Get URI of .mp3 file stored in res/raw folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android)

***If you want to get any resource URI then there are two ways :***

1. **Using Resource Name**

> Syntax : android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]
>
> Example :
>   Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/icon");

2. **Using Resource Id**

> Syntax : android.resource://[package]/[resource_id]
>
> Example : Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" +
>   R.drawable.icon);

***These were the examples to get the URI of any image file stored in drawable folder.
Similarly you can get URIs of res/raw folder.***

> IMO the second way would be preferred as renaming the resource etc can
>   be easily refactored.

***Set the data source like so:***

```
CONSTANTS.RES_PREFIX = "android.resource://com.my.package/"
```

> ```
> mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),
>               Uri.parse(CONSTANTS.RES_PREFIX + R.raw.id));
> ```