# Feeding data from memory to MediaPlayer

Tags: android

Scenario:
Have encrypted mp3 files in my .apk.  Need to decrypt and send to MediaPlayer object.

Problem:
After I read the files and decrypt them, how do I get MediaPlayer to play them ?

Now.  MediaPlayer has 4 versions of setDataSource().

```
setDataSource(String path)
setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)
setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)
setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)
```

None of which are ideal for the situation.  Guess ideal would be to give MediaPlayer an InputStream ?

Possible solutions:

- Write decrypted data to file play
  that file.  A lot of IO overhead.
- Create a dummy http server
  (ServerSocket ?) and pass the url to
  MediaPlayer.  Again, messy.  Am I
  even allowed to create a socket.

Does anyone have a better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] callData = ...;
String base64EncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(callData, Base64.DEFAULT);

try
{
    String url = "data:audio/amr;base64,"+base64EncodedString;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need all the functionality in MediaPlayer, I recommend trying  [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).  It's meant for basically what you describe.  Unfortunately, MediaPlayer doesn't take an AudioTrack in its constructor, so the best solution in that case is to include a dummy Http server that sends your data back from a URL (which is what the Android 1.0 release notes recommends).

Comment: I did think about AudioTrack and forgot to mention it in my post :) It's however much more low level than MediaPlayer.  Like it says "It allows to stream PCM audio buffers to the audio hardware for playback".  I'd have to decode the MP3 myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure, but I don't think you have any other option than to temporarily save the the decrypted file before playing it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283499/setting-data-source-to-an-raw-id-in-mediaplayer) is kind of similar, but I don't think you use the easy solution suggested there since you have an encrypted file. There is also provided a link to a tutorial for [Custom Audio Streaming with MediaPlayer](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/), but it seems like their solution also use a temporary file.