# Get URI of .mp3 file stored in res/raw folder in android

Tags: android, audio, share

I have many .mp3 files stored in res/raw folder.

I am getting URI of .mp3 file using following code.

```
Uri.parse("android.resource:///com.my.android.sharesound/"+resId);
```

This returns : `android.resource:///com.my.android.sharesound/2130968609`

Now I am using this URI in creating Share Intent

```
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.android.sharesound/"+resId));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share Sound");
```

When i select any Mail application eg. Gmail or YahooMail from the Share Intent, the mp3 file attached successfully. But it shows that 2130968609(as an attachment)

i dont want resourceId(2130968609) to appear.

I want to display fileName.mp3

How can i do that? Am i missing something ?

OR

Is there any other way to attach .mp3 file stored in res/raw to mail via Share Intent.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Finally after searching a lot i found the solution.

If you want to get any resource URI then there are two ways :

1. Using Resource Name

   Syntax  : `android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]`

   Example :  `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/icon");`
2. Using Resource Id

   Syntax  : `android.resource://[package]/[resource_id]`

   Example : `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.drawable.icon);`

This were the examples to get the URI of any image file stored in drawable folder.

Similarly you can get URIs of res/raw folder.

In my case i used 1st way ie. Using Resource Name

Comment: thanks for the answer.
IMO, I think the second way would be preferred as renaming the resource etc can be easily refactored. Hence, I chose that.

Comment: to aid the refactoring, you can also replace package name with `Context.getPackageName()`

Comment: Oh, just to continue the fun tidbits, you can use `File.separator` instead of hardcoding `/`. And, you could go crazy with `File.pathSeparator` instead of hardcoding `:`. Also, great answer!

Comment: `"android.resource"` = `ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE`

Comment: If you want to use this URL in a WebView, at least in Lollipop (I did not try other versions) you need to set a custom WebViewClient that handles those URLs, something like this: 
`public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
  if (url.startsWith(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://")) {
   int idPos = url.lastIndexOf('/');
   int id = Integer.parseInt(url.substring(idPos + 1));
   return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "", resources.openRawResource(id));
  }
  return null;
 }`

Comment: @KyleJahnke How do you solved this in Lollipop, a few points in right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: I have a case that there are 2 localized raw folder, default raw and raw-en.
In my device settings, it's using English. When I share file via intent: sharingIntent.putExtra(
     Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
     Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name
));
it always share file in **raw-en** (might be affected by device's setting).
**Is there any way to share exact file in *raw* folder regardless device's settings?**

Answer (score 47):

This work like magic:
Assuming the mp3 is saved in the raw folder as

> notification_sound.mp3

then simple doing this works:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/notification_sound");
```

Answer (score 16):

Don't construct string on your own, use `Uri.Builder`:

```
/**
 * @param resourceId identifies an application resource
 * @return the Uri by which the application resource is accessed
 */
internal fun Context.getResourceUri(@AnyRes resourceId: Int): Uri = Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
    .authority(packageName)
    .path(resourceId.toString())
    .build()
```

From AOSP-DeskClock.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Amazing.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some methods that might help someone:

```
    public Uri getRawUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + filename);
    }
    public Uri getDrawableUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + filename);
    }
    public Uri getMipmapUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/mipmap/" + filename);
    }
```

Just call the method like this:

```
Uri rawUri = getRawUri("myFile.filetype");
```

Comment: ContentResolver, getPackageName() ??? what import to get these working?

Comment: context - context.getPackageName()

Comment: you need an extra `File.separator` in there after the `File.pathSeparator`

Comment: Yes above doesn't work. This works:        public Uri getRawUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator+File.separator + getPackageName()+File.separator +"raw"+File.separator+filename);
    }

Answer (score 2):

One line Answer

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext(),Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.fileName)).play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean way to get any resource,

```
 Uri.parse(String.format("android.resource://%s/%s/%s",this.getPackageName(),"resource_folder_name","file_name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the file to your SDCard and maybe then send the new URI,

```
 public boolean saveAs(int resSoundId){
 byte[] buffer = null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(resSoundId);
 int size=0;

 try {
  size = fIn.available();
  buffer = new byte[size];
  fIn.read(buffer);
  fIn.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 }

 String path = "/sdcard/yourapp/temp/";
 String filename = "filename"+".mp3";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

 FileOutputStream save;
 try {
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
  save.write(buffer);
  save.flush();
  save.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 }
```

Remember to delete the file after the email is sent successfully.

Comment: Thanks Reno. But dont you think it will take some amount of time to write the file to sdcard, get uri and then delete it. ?.. Delete will create problem for me. When should i delete the file ?. We cannot predict the Share Intent apps. result.

Comment: True, this is only a workaround, in-case you don't get anything. Delete the temp directory when your app closes.

Comment: @Kartik [Try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888718/android-share-images-from-assets-folder/7177103#7177103), it worked for someone.

Comment: ok. i think there is no other way to get URI of res. I am having other question but related to this only. When i select any Mail app, file gets attached. But when i select Whatsapp, it asks me to choose contact but doesnot show the file attached.

Comment: I really don't know how Whatsapp handles their attachment intents, and yes, go for whichever option is convenient

Comment: I got it working : see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android/7979084#7979084