# Obtaining thumbnail of pdf present in assets folder gives file not found exception

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin

I am trying to extract a bitmap image from pdf.
I am following this post from stack overflow
[Generate Thumbnail of Pdf in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828396/generate-thumbnail-of-pdf-in-android)

My Pdf file is located in the assets folder

```
private var quaranPdfUri = "quran.pdf"
```

I tried the following ways to open the pdf from assets folder

```
1.val parcelFileDescriptor  = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/$quaranPdfUri"),"r")
2. val parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/$quaranPdfUri"),"r")?.parcelFileDescriptor
3. val parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/$quaranPdfUri"))
```

But in all the above cases i am getting file not found exception.

I went through a bunch of post on stack overflow to obtain uri of file present in assets folder, but i keep getting file not found exception

[How to get URI from an asset File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file)
[Get Uri from file in either assets or res/raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144837/get-uri-from-file-in-either-assets-or-res-raw)
[How to pass a file path which is in assets folder to File(String path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820142/how-to-pass-a-file-path-which-is-in-assets-folder-to-filestring-path)

Comment: have you unzipped your APK to check the file is therE?

Comment: @Blundell The file is present 100  percent. I have the project in front of me. I am opening the pdf for some other screen as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:///android_asset/` works for `WebView` and little else.

Try this:

```
val context = TODO() // get a Context from somewhere
val assetFd = context.assets.openFd("quran.pdf")
val parcelFileDescriptor = assetFd.getParcelFileDescriptor()
```

Basically, use [`AssetManager` and `openFd()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#openFd(java.lang.String)) to get an `AssetFileDescriptor`, then use `getParcelFileDescriptor()` to get a `ParcelFileDescriptor` to try handing to your `PdfiumCore`.

If that does not work, see how he's handling it in AndroidPdfViewer. That definitely supports assets and uses PdfiumAndroid, so somehow he is getting assets to work.