# Referring to file in drawable to create Uri

Tags: android, android-file

I want to set the image `res/drawable-hdpi/nasa_image.jpg` as the wallpaper.

I wrote the following code but it raises the `FileNotFoundException`.

```
Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(new File("res/drawable-hdpi/nasa_image.jpg"));
Uri u2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/nasa_image.jpg");
Uri u3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.drawable.nasa_image);
WallpaperManager w = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

Bitmap bitmap;
try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(u));
    w.setBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

First I tried for `u1`. It didn't work. Then I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android). I then tried `u2` and `u3`.

I checked the log. Every time it gave the same `FileNotFoundException`.

How to refer to it? Where am I wrong? Am I taking the wrong root directory?

Comment: why can't you just use `w.setResource(R.drawable.nasa_image)`?

Comment: I saw the method later and tried it. But it is also giving `IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the Activity`. Can you suggest what can be wrong? All this code is on button click.

Comment: can you post a stack trace?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting it. I needed to grant the permission.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a wrong way to do that in android. why don't you use the resource identifier?

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(nasa_image, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable=res.getDrawable(id);
imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

or

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nasa_image);
imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
imgView.setImageDrawable();
```

Update to convert from drawable to bitmap just use this (assuming that your drawable is an `instanceof Bitmapdrawable`)

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

Use this method if you are not sure about drawable instance

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Use this method if you are sure that you the right file path

```
 private Drawable getDrawable(String path) {
      File imgFile = new File(path);
      if (imgFile.exists()) {
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
         return new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);
      }
      return null;
   }
```

you can adjust it to return bitmap or drawable according to your issue

Comment: This is fine but I need `Bitmap` object to use `w.setBitmap` method.

Comment: @Shashwat simple just use this Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(); to convert from drawable to bitmap

Comment: I have just found a method to set the wallpaper `w.setResource(R.drawable.nasa_image)`. But still thank you for suggesting it. Is there any way by which we can refer the file using the filename?

Comment: I didn't find any method `res.getDrawable`. To convert from resource id to `Drawable` we can do ` Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);`. You can make your answer clear.

Comment: I you know the absolut path you can also get the bitmap or drawable from a file. look at my update @Shashwat

Comment: Thats what I was struggling for in the question. What should be the string for the path?

Comment: use this file:///android_asset/..., where ... is the stuff inside your assets/   @Shashwat

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the extention (.jpg)
Use:

`Uri.parse("android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/drawable/nasa_image");`

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Uri u1 = Uri.parse("R.drawable.nasa_image");
```

Comment: This is not working. `R.drawable.nasa_image` should be without quotes.