# Playing mp3 voice for android application on clicking button

Tags: android, mp3, android-video-player

hi i am developing android application in which i need to play a saved mp3 voice when someone click on button. on clicking button another activity will be opened and saved voice should be played
how can i do it??

Regards

Comment: have you tried searching search for mediaplayer class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a service to play MP3 via [android.media.MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Second, you can put your saved MP3 in res/raw folder. (manual create it, if it doesn't exist)

And this could help : [Get URI of .mp3 file stored in res/raw folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android)

......

cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int res = getResources().getIdentifier ( "yourfile", "raw","your.package.here" );
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create ( YourActivity.this, res );
        mPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

You should create a directory *res/raw* with the file *yourfile.mp3* in it