# No sound when setting default notification sound

Tags: java, android, audio

I am trying to set the default notification sound to a .mp3 file from the raw directory. When I set it, it shows the name of the file correctly but no sound plays. What am I doing wrong?

```
File f = new File("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName()
                                                        + "/" + files.get(pos));

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, names.get(pos));
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, f.length());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

Uri u = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
context.getContentResolver().delete(
                                u, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" 
                                       + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
final Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(u, values);

Log.d("URI", uri.toString() + "\n" 
                                     + uri.getPath() + "\n" 
                                     + uri.getEncodedPath());

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, 
                                            RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, 
                                            uri);
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri).play();
```

This is the logcat:

```
D/URI: content://media/internal/audio/media/158
               /internal/audio/media/158
               /internal/audio/media/158
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
D/Ringtone: Problem opening; delegating to remote player
```

I think the problem is that it is looking for the file in `/internal/audio/media/` but it should be looking in `/res/raw/`. How do I change this?

---

I have tried to set the default notification sound 2 other ways. The first way sets the sound, but the name displayed it the mp3 id. The second way displays the right name, but does not play any sound. This is my code:

```
//no name, sound
final Uri u1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + files.get(pos));

//no sound, name
File file = new File("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + files.get(pos), names.get(pos));
final Uri u2 = Uri.fromFile(file);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, u1);
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, u1).play();
```

`files.get(pos)` returns the id of the mp3 file in `/res/raw/` and `names.get(pos)` returns the name I want to display. How can I set the name to `u1`, or why will `u2` not play any sound? When using `u2` I get this logcat:

```
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
D/Ringtone: Problem opening; delegating to remote player
```

Comment: Have you exhausted all the existing answers .like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-

Comment: Yes, I have looked at many other answers and have not found one that works. Most say to do it the way I am doing it, but I cannot get it to play any sound.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android

Comment: When I do it that way the sound plays, but the name for the notification sound is set as the id of the mp3 file. Is there a way to set the name? I added the code I tried.