# android - how to get path of mp3 stored in raw folder

Tags: android, android-resources

After searching for solution, I have found from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android) that it is possible to retrieve path like:

**Using Resource Id**

Syntax : `android.resource://[package]/[resource_id]`

Example : `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.mp3filename);`

Which is exactly what I want. Problem is that, I'm using lolipop, and it does not work. When the package/resource is parsed, path from Uri.parse will be null. Is there other way around to write this, since in my Song class, I have only access to resourceId (R.raw.mp3filename).

Comment: "and it seems it does not work" -- what is "it"? "returns null for path" -- *what* returns `null`? `Uri.parse()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare It returns null for path when I try to parse the above example

Comment: What do you mean by "null for path"? A `Uri` is not a path, any more than `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816944/android-how-to-get-path-of-mp3-stored-in-raw-folder?noredirect=1#comment61206631_36816944` is a path. Are you saying that `Uri.parse()` itself is returning `null`? Or are you trying to do something with that `Uri` (e.g., call `getPath()` on it), and *that* is returning `null`?

Comment: Alright, I have a simple question now: "Is it possible to get file path by using R.raw.mp3file" and how? - And to answer on your question, on what i'm going to do with URI, yes i was trying with Uri instance to call getPath() method, which in my case is returning null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get file path by using R.raw.mp3file

No, because it is not a file on the device. It is a file on the hard drive of your development machine. On the device, it is merely an entry in an APK file.

Either:

- Do whatever you are trying to do some other way that does not involve a file path, or
- Use `openInputStream()` on a `Resources` object (you can get one from any `Context` via `getResources()`), and use Java I/O to copy the contents of that resource to a local file, such as on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)

Comment: Thank you on the answer. I will go more into details by tommorow. :)