# android - retrieve all files from /res/raw folder as File type

Tags: java, android

How can I retrieve all the files in /res/raw folder as File?
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539715/android-how-do-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder#answer-20879359) solution, and "New Folder" value I have replaced with "res/raw" as you can see in the following code:

```
public File[] getRawFiles() {
        File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "res/raw");
        return yourDir.listFiles();
}
```

When program is started, I get an exception on line `return yourDir.listFiles`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

How can I fix this, and what is correct path to "res/raw/" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I retrieve all the files in /res/raw folder as File?

You cannot do this. As [we discussed yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816944/android-how-to-get-path-of-mp3-stored-in-raw-folder), resources are not files on the filesystem of the device. They are files on your development machine. They are merely entries in an APK file on the device.

Either:

- Do whatever you are trying to do some other way that does not involve files, or
- Use `openInputStream()` on a `Resources` object (you can get one from any `Context` via `getResources()`), and use Java I/O to copy the contents of a resource to a local file, such as on [internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816944/android-how-to-get-path-of-mp3-stored-in-raw-folder), and [using reflection to iterate over the actual resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540269/115145), or
- Switch to using `assets/` instead of `res/raw/`, as `AssetManager` allows you to `list()` assets (though you still only get an `InputStream` on an asset, as like resources, assets are not files on the device)

Comment: Ok, so that is how it is. However (the following question may be off-topic), but main problem, or what I'm trying to achieve, is that I need to set path for `new MediaMetadataRetriever().setDataSource()` in order to collect some data regarding that mp3 file. How do I get that path and set that value to `setDataSource(path)` ?

Comment: @Kapparino: There are six versions of `setDataSource()` on [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html), taking different parameters. If nothing else, use the one that takes a `MediaDataSource`, then implement a `MediaDataSource` that wraps your desired resource or asset. Also, for any of the methods on `Resources` or `AssetManager` that return an `AssetFileDescriptor`, you can call `getFileDescriptor()` on that to get a `FileDescriptor` to pass into `setDataSource()`.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for disturbing, can you please check following image: `http://i.imgur.com/9VQ6UdE.png` I'm getting null for data as you can see on the image, although values are actually set for file.

Comment: @Kapparino: I have no idea, sorry.