# How to get an uri from a raw resource

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a .txt file inside my raw folder. I want to get the uri of the file and create a new file to upload to firebase.

The idea is simple

1. Get the txt file from my res/raw resources
2. Upload it to firebase storage

**I have done this**

```
 String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "raw/grupos.txt";

 Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
```

**but when I call**

```
riversRef.putFile(file)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {....
```

**it says that the file is invalid**

**LOGCAT**

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /android.resource:/com.example.usuario.ottasubirarchivos/raw/grupos.txt:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I don't know if I need to get the path of the resource file, create a new file inside the internal storage, get that file and upload it to firebase, or either use stream... I don't know how to handle this... Thanks

Comment: String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + ".txt" + "raw/grupos.txt";

Comment: something like that?

Comment: i tried and isnt working

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` only works with a filesystem path. Use `Uri.parse()` to parse something that already is a `Uri`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
public class UriUtils {

    public static Uri getUriToResource(@NonNull Context context, @AnyRes int resId) throws Resources.NotFoundException {
        Resources res = context.getResources();

        Uri resUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                "://" + res.getResourcePackageName(resId)
                + '/' + res.getResourceTypeName(resId)
                + '/' + res.getResourceEntryName(resId));
        return resUri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this working?
I can access a raw resource this way: `Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + ApplicationContext.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.beep)`
With the file `beep.ogg` located under `Resources/raw` directory. What I've noticed here are: the capital letter in `Raw`, `Resource` and not Resource`S` and the extensionless filename in my path. As noted by CommonsWare in comments you don't have a file but its Uri so parse it directly