# Android: Start Default Audio Intent from res file

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, mp3

I am trying to play an audio file present in res/raw directory using the default audio player from my app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.format("android.resource://%s/%s/%s",getContext().getPackageName(),"raw","fade")), "audio/*");     

startActivity(intent);
```

However, every time I am getting exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.example.android.punjabi/raw/fade typ=audio/* launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
```

I have tried out the ways mentioned in here:

[Get URI of .mp3 file stored in res/raw folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android)

It still gives me the same exception.

Any help please. I don't want to use the MediaPlayer class to play the audio. I want to use the default audio player on the phone to play it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for any device to have an app capable of supporting playing back audio from a `Uri` using the under-utilized `android:resource` scheme.

Either:

- Play it yourself using `MediaPlayer`, or
- Copy the contents of that resource to a file, then use `FileProvider` to serve it up using a `content` `Uri`

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, 

Playing it using MediaPlayer is not really an option. Doing so, I'll have to manage play/pause/stop, seekbar in a runnable, save the state on orientation change etc. 

I would like to keep it as simple as possible. About your point 2, can you give me some example by which I can achieve this? or may be if I move my files to assests directory? Will this help?

Comment: @Manpreet: "can you give me some example by which I can achieve this?" -- get a `Resources` object via `getResources()` on your activity. Call `openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream` on your raw resource. From there, it's standard Java I/O. "if I move my files to assests directory? Will this help?" -- no, sorry.