# URI from string is crashing the app. Am I using it wrong?

Tags: string, android-studio, kotlin, uri

In the raw directory I have files named rhode1.mp3 to rhode49.mp3.

I need to randomly play one of these files so I'm randomly generating a number and attaching it to `R.raw.rhode` to use as URI (`uri1` in the code below), but it crashes the app. When I replace `uri1` with `R.raw.rhode1` for example it works and the audio file plays.

I tried writing `R.raw.rhode$note1.mp3` and it still didn't work. Also tried:

```
("R.raw.rhode" + note1.toString() + ".mp3")
```

And:

```
("R.raw.rhode" + note1.toString())
```

override fun onCreate (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var mediaplayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    val letsgo = findViewById<Button>(R.id.start)
    val think = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.think)
    val extime = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.extime)
    val rpt = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.rpt)
    val rtime = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.rtime)
    var note1: Int
    var uri1: Uri

    letsgo.setOnClickListener {

        note1 = Random.nextInt(49) + 1
        uri1 = Uri.parse("R.raw.rhode" + note1.toString())
        mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, uri1)
        mediaplayer!!.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

`R.resourceType.resourceName` is a valid symbol from the point of the programming language. But it is, obviously, not an URL/URI.

Here is a sample of how to construct a resource URI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979084/3050249

Comment: Tried to fix this for 3h yesterday (in vain). Thank you so much.
For people with the same problem, fix:
uri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/rhode" + note1.toString())
for some reason this:
uri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/R.raw.rhode" + note1.toString())
which was also proposed in that link did not work.