# Android MediaPlayer volume is very low ( already adjusted Volume )

Tags: java, android, media-player

I m using the MediaPlayer to play one of the internal alarm ringtone.
i m using the setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f) to maximize the volume when the ringtone is played. but the ringtone doesn't play full volume ( when I compare it to playing the ringtone separately or through the built it android alarm)

here is my code

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, ringtoneUri);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(looping);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

I added the following permission  android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
 ( not sure if this is needed )

Any Idea why the mediaPlayer still won't play the sound at maximum?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

```
AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume, 0);

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM); // this is important.

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, ringtoneUri);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(looping);  
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: excellent answer, thanks a bunch!!! -> if you don't know how to set a ringtoneUri from a raw mp3 this might be handy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20111291/2135941

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same issue, and then noticed this this in the [MediaPlayer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> While in the Prepared state, properties such as audio/sound volume, screenOnWhilePlaying, looping can be adjusted by invoking the corresponding set methods.

Calling `setVolume` *after* calling `prepare` fixes this, so that audio is played at max volume. Actually, according to the docs I just quoted, you should call `setLooping` after `prepare` as well:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, ringtoneUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.setLooping(looping);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setAudioStreamType() is now deprecated you should use the method setAudioAttributes() instead. Below is the full example

```
var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
fun playAudio(audioUrl: String) {

        mediaPlayer.apply {
            if (isPlaying) {
                stop()
                reset()
                release()
            }
        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        try {

            mediaPlayer.apply {
                setAudioAttributes(
                    AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .build()
                )
                setVolume(2f,2f)
                setDataSource(audioUrl)
                prepare()
                start()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```