# Why multiple Android resources have the same int representation?

Tags: android, resources

I have 5 different videos in my raw folder in Android project made with Eclipse, but the problem is that

```
    String stringPath1 = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.firstVideo; 
    String stringPath2 = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.secondVideo;
```

when I display stringPath1 and stringPath2 in textview they are the same (R.raw._ is the same int). Therefore when I try to change videoPlayer path the path does not change. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using path use `InputStream`.

to get the stream :

`getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.firstVideo)`

`getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.secondVideo)`

Good Luck.

Comment: Ok, but what I have to call instead of VideoView.setVideoPath() to set the source of video?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283499/setting-data-source-to-an-raw-id-in-mediaplayer