# Android media player status=0x1 error, want to play sound

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to load/play a sound `(I have file /res/raw/fx2.wav)` with the code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fx2);
```

or

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fx2);
```

And i get this error:

> java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

I searched this error but none of the answers had working code.
Such examples also had:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

and then something with:
`FileInputStream
or
mp.setDataSrouce`

I am experimenting with these but I have nothing working so far and I don't know what method is best for me or in what situations they should be used? I simply want to load and play a sound.

It might be I am just not getting the context properly. Or there is something wrong with my sound file(but it is a normal small way so I think it is not this).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a permission for reading files from external memory in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

You should also try to change the path to your file using following code (change `com.example.myapp` to your package name):

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapp/" + R.raw.fx2);
mp.setDataSourceUri(this, uri);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281340/4179315) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Make sure you are importing:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
```